# Specify data to be graphed by one parameter

Tags: r

I want to be able to graph some points based on if one parameter is true in a data frame. I want to only use the position coordinates if in the "Time" column is equal to 2. How do I write this in R?

Comment: Something like `plot( exampledata$DataToPlot[exampledata$Time == 2, ] )` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the future it'd helpful to `dput` some data. The packages `dplyr` and `ggplot2` are two popular packages you might want to look into.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Create something that your data might look like:

```
df <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10), Time = sample(1:2, 10, replace = T))
```

Filter then plot:

```
df_tmp <- df %>% filter(Time == 2)
ggplot(df_tmp, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```